# Devise 'Forgot password' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am using devise for my rails 3 app, when i click forgot password, enter the email and click submit, i get the error

```
undefined method `successfully_sent?' for #<Devise::PasswordsController:0xac17e74>
```

i have uncommented  the line `config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"`  in devise.rb in initializers
also i have put

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

in development.rb

please help!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I updated the version of the Dvise from 1.4.8 to 1.5.2.

After down graded to 1.4.8, the forgot password function goes well.